# Hidden_field not working with model validations in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a hidden_field in my bids form to add post_id to bids:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :post_id, :value => @post.id %>
```

However, when I add validations to my bids model - for example:

```
class Bid < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  validates :price, presence: true
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :company_email, presence: true, 
                format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX}

end
```

I get the following error only when one of my validations fails. If none fail, the bid gets saved correctly:

NoMethodError in Bids#create: undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass and

```
<%= f.hidden_field :post_id, :value => @post.id %>
```

gets highlighted in red.

Bids controller:

```
class BidsController < ApplicationController

def new
    @bid = Bid.new
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def show
    @bid = bids.find(params[:id])
end

def index
    @bid = bids.all
end

def create 
    @bid = Bid.new(bid_params)
    if @bid.save
        redirect_to root_path
        flash[:notice] = 'Bid received!'
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def bid_params
    params.require(:bid).permit(:price, :company_name, :company_street, :company_city,
                                :company_zip, :company_phone, :company_email, :post_id)
end

end
```

Bids form

```
<%= form_for(@bid) do |f| %>
 <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
  <div style='float: left; width: 50%;'>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

   <%= f.label "Price" %>
   <%= f.text_field :price, class: "form-control" %>

   <%= f.hidden_field :post_id, :value => @post.id %>

   <%= f.submit "Submit bid", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

 <% end %>
```

Comment: please check the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your create action:
When your validation failed it is executing the following:

```
    # on create action
    else
        render 'new'
    end
```

right? That means it will render the new action's view file. But have you noticed that here in this create action there is no such @post instance variables where you load you Post?
So do the little trick just like following:

```
    else
        @post = Post.find(bid_params[:post_id])
        render 'new'
    end
```

So now, you have loaded your post record on @post instance variables. Action render :new means you are just rendering that view file of new action method of this controller .

Hope you get my point!

Answer (score 0):

Your params[:id] is not passed again to the new action when the validation fails. You can either :

- Submit another hidden_field with params[:id] :

  ```
  <%= f.hidden_field :post_id, :value => params[:id] %>
  ```

and then in your `new` action :

```
def new
 @bid = Bid.new
 @post = Post.find(params[:id]) || Post.find(params[:post_id])
end
```

- Or render with the id parameter in your create action if the validation fails :

  ```
  def create 
   @bid = Bid.new(bid_params)
   if @bid.save
    redirect_to root_path
    flash[:notice] = 'Bid received!'
   else
    render 'new', id: params[:id]
   end
  end
  ```